# Troubles retrieving files with special characters in the path

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I ran a bunch of m/r reports over date ranges and now have a series of directories like:

```
/user/michael/output/TrueListingSellThroughFromLeafCategory/{20120101,20120102,20120103,20120104,20120105,20120106,20120107}
/user/michael/output/TrueListingSellThroughFromLeafCategory/{20120108,20120109,20120110,20120111,20120112,20120113,20120114}
/user/michael/output/TrueListingSellThroughFromLeafCategory/{20120115,20120116,20120117,20120118,20120119,20120120,20120121}
```

I'm having a great deal of difficulty browsing these directories. If I try to `ls` one of these, it takes the dates as a list and looks for different directories for each one. If I escape the braces I get a no such file or directory error. It's similar if I replace the braces with %7B and %7D.

If I wildcard that level then I can browse lower:

```
/user/michael/output/TrueListingSellThroughFromLeafCategory/*
```

But it would be nice to retrieve them one at a time! How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to fix it with the regex operator `?`

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/michael/output/TrueListingSellThroughFromLeafCategory/?20120101,20120102,20120103,20120104,20120105,20120106,20120107?
```

I tested on my box and it seems to work:

```
[cmenguy@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp/{TEST}
[cmenguy@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -put <(echo foo) /tmp/{TEST}/
[cmenguy@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /tmp/{TEST}
ls: Cannot access /tmp/{TEST}: No such file or directory.
[cmenguy@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -ls '/tmp/\{TEST\}'
ls: Illegal file pattern: Expecting set closure character or end of range, or } for glob {TEST at 5
[cmenguy@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /tmp/?TEST?
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 cmenguy supergroup        4 2013-01-24 05:59 /tmp/{TEST}/63
```

Looks like this is still work in progress as described in [HDFS-3557](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-3557), it seems to be specific to 0.20.2 (if you're using Cloudera this still affects cdh3u* versions so you'd probably need to use cdh4)